# I can't delete a folder on an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, permission

I have two external hard drives and I copied everything from the first drive to the second. This included a `/Volumes/NAS/TOSHIBA EXT/$RECYCLE.BIN` folder where `TOSHIBA EXT` was the name of my first drive and `NAS` is my second drive.

I now want to delete the copy of the drive, but I get a permission denied error (even w/ `sudo`, or as root). I tried `chmod` and `chown` as well, nothing seems to work. Going into finder, deleting it there throws an error as well where it asks me to make sure no files are locked. And none are. The only folder in the entire `/TOSHIBA EXT/` directory is now `$RECYCLE.BIN` which is not locked. I can't even ls the `$RECYCLE.BIN` directory. If it matters NAS is a network drive connected to a Raspberry Pi that I mounted to my Mac through SMB

Comment: “root” on your Mac is not the same “root” on your NAS.  It may be the same name, but it’s two totally different users.  This appears to be a permissions issue.  To solve, log into your NAS, then using the root on that account, move/copy/delete the files as needed.